# Laravel query to output json data as select list. How to amend existing code to concatenate two values

Tags: laravel

I've got a pre-existing function in my controller that will run a simple query and return the model_name and id then return the result as json.

```
public function getModel($id) 
{
    $models = DB::table('model')->where('man_id',$id)->pluck('model_name','id');
    return json_encode($models);
}
```

New requirement is that I include an additional column named model_num with the query. Plan is to concatenate the model_name and model_num columns.

Tried the following, but it doesn't return any values and I get a 404 response for the json:

```
public function getModel($id) 
{
    $models = DB::table("model")->select("id","CONCAT(model_name, '-', model_num) as model")->where("man_id",$id)->pluck('model','id');
    return json_encode($models);
}
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: You changed `pluck` to `get` was that intentional?

Comment: Why not pluck all 3 attributes and concatenate later as needed

Comment: @apokryfos It was not intentional, no. I have revised my code above. Now I'm getting a 500 response from the console.

Comment: Maybe resources are an option for you to extract the json generation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using SQL functions within a `select` these will probably not work. You can use `selectRaw` instead:

```
public function getModel($id) 
{
    $models = DB::table("model")
        ->selectRaw("id, CONCAT(model_name, '-', model_num) as model")
        ->where("man_id",$id)
        ->pluck('model','id');
    return response()->json($models); // response()->json() is preferable
}
```

alternatively you can do the concatenating in the PHP side:

```
public function getModel($id) 
{
    $models = DB::table("model")
        ->select("id", "model_name" "model_num")
        ->where("man_id",$id)
        ->get()
        ->mapWithKeys(function ($model) {
            return [ $model->id => $model->model_name.'-'.$model->model_num ];
        })
    return response()->json($models);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

public function getModel($id) 
    {
      $models = DB::table('model')->where('man_id',$id)->first() ;
    $models->model = $models->model_name. '-'. $models->model_num;
        return json_encode($models->pluck('model', 'id');
}